# How do I annotate onto a select_related model?

Tags: django, orm

I am selected a related object for each object in my queryset. How can I annotate a computed value for each one?

Model:

```py
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)


class Student(Entity):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
```

I want to fetch all teachers and for each one their school, and the number of students in that school.

This is what I tried:

```py
teachers = Teacher.objects.select_related('school').annotate(student_count=Count('school__student'))
```

But I can see that this is wrong as the student count needs to be *per school*.

I'd expect to be able to do something like this with my queryset afterwards:

```py
for teacher in teachers:
  print(teacher.name, teacher.school.name, teacher.school.student_count)
```

Comment: You can just fetch it with `teacher.student_count`. You always annotate on the model you are querying with. Since in your modeling, a teacher belongs to a *single* school, the result is not different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I can see that this is wrong as the student count needs to be *per school*.

Well you will count the students that belong to the school to which that teacher belongs, so this is semantically valid. The annotation will however be put on the objects in the queryset, hence the teacher, so you can fetch the student count with:

```
for teacher in teachers:
  print(teacher.name, teacher.school.name, teacher.student_count)
```

Since multiple teachers can belong to the *same* school, annotating in such way might nog be the best idea, since if not optimized, it means that you will count the number of students for that school for each teacher. Although semantically that does not change anything, the query might take considerable time.

You could decide to use a `.prefetch_related(..)` for the given `school`, and annotate that queryset in the [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects), this will result in extra queries, but less expensive ones. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Count

teachers = Teacher.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'school',
        queryset=School.objects.annotate(student_count=Count('student'))
    )
)
```

Then you can indeed query with:

```
for teacher in teachers:
  print(teacher.name, teacher.school.name, teacher.school.student_count)
```

Comment: Yes this gets to the heart of it. Thank you.

Although the schools can be `select_related` so they're loaded with a join, the counts should be fetched on a `prefetch_related` queryset, so that like you say if there's many teachers belonging to few schools (obviously likely in reality) the count is only done a few times instead of many.

So you can't `select_related` the school itself but `prefetch_related` the computed `school.student_count`? I guess how would it stitch the two together :(.

Comment: @PaulMitchell-Gears: well usually the last one will result only in two queries iirc. It is Django that then "statiches" the schools together to the teachers. I think two queries is not that expensive, especially since we made the queries probably a lot cheaper, than what we can hope for with the `.select_related(..)` variant.